# cvMatchTemplate finds match without one

Tags: opencv

I use opencv and need to find a match on picture which is taken from video flow. Functions cvMatchTemplate() and cvMinMaxLoc() finds the match absolutely correct. But the problem is that when there is no match, opencv finds it anyway. Even on white sheet. 
Can anyone say what the problem is? Maybe use another function to detect match or to some to understand that there are no match? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`cvMatchTemplate` ouputs a map of similarity measures/image distances (depends on the `method` parameter). You want to have a look at the similarity measures and threshold them at a reasonable value (so, only accept a match if the similarity is high/distance is low). `cvMinMaxLoc` also gives you the values, you can use those for thresholding (look at values for positive and negative samples, and set the threshold in between).